# On scroll React Native Animated do the animation but flickering

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, animation, react-hooks

In my react native app I'm trying to animate opacity of a View.
When I scroll, I saw the animation do the job, but it’s flickering at the same time. I don’t know why.

Video example :  https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/102861040538120192/560165613092339734/video.mov

Here is the code I made

```
const Scrollable = () => {
  const largeHeaderSize = useState({
    height: 0,
    y: 0
  });

  const animatedValueScrollY = new Animated.Value(largeHeaderSize.height);
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

  const headerOpacity = animatedValueScrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, largeHeaderSize.height],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
    extrapolate: "clamp"
  });

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
        borderBottomWidth:
          scrollY >= largeHeaderSize.height ? StyleSheet.hairlineWidth : 0
      }}>
        <View>
          <Animated.View style={{ zIndex: 1, opacity: headerOpacity }}>
            <Text>Title</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: animatedValueScrollY } } }],
          {
            useNativeDriver: true,
            listener: event => setScrollY(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
          }
        )}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        contentInset={{
          top: 0,
          bottom: 50
        }}
        contentOffset={{
          y: 0
        }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

How I can I solve that?

Comment: try disabling **JS Dev Mode** whille testing your animation ... from the developer menu

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli I have the problem on real device too? Do you think it can solve that?

Comment: it's the same for both emulator and physical device ... it's always recommened to disable JS Dev Mode when testing animations

Comment: It's doesn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use the useRef hook like so:

```
const animatedValueScrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0))

const headerOpacity = animatedValueScrollY.current.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0, largeHeaderSize.height],
   outputRange: [1, 0],
   extrapolate: 'clamp'
});
```